# Technical information using dropdown values to pass to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am having difficulty in doing the following and if anyone can give me an idea how I can achieve the following:

Upon a new selection in the dropdown, I call the action Status and passing the selected value in the dropdown as parameter.

I have a dropdown as follows in my view

```
@Html.DropDownList("Status", Model.DisplayStatus)
```

---

In My controller, I am having

```
private ActionResult Status(string active = "All")
     {
         UserModel model = new UserModel(active);
         return View("Users", model);
     }
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use strongly typed helpers and jquery. Like this:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Statuses
    {
        get
        {
            return new[]
            {
                new SelectListItem { Value = "online", Text = "Online" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "offline", Text = "Offline" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "all", Text = "All" },
            };
        }
    }
}
```

then a controller:

```
public class HomeController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new MyViewModel());
    }

    public ActionResult Status(string status)
    {
        UserModel model = new UserModel(status);
        return View("Users", model);
    }
}
```

and finally the view:

```
@model AppName.Models.MyViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Status", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myForm" }))
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(
        x => x.Status, 
        new SelectList(Model.Statuses, "Value", "Text"),
        new { id = "status" }
    )
}
```

and some script to attach to the change event and submit the form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#status').change(function() {
        $('myForm').trigger('submit');
    });
});
</script>
```